# How can I make the flag to be true and false but each time only once?

Tags: unity, c#

This simple class is attached to some objects in the game :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum InteractableMode
    {
        Description,
        Action,
        ActionWithoutThrow
    };

    public InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Description;
    public float distance;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string description = "";

    public bool IsAnyAction()
    {
        return interactableMode == InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow || interactableMode == InteractableMode.Action;
    }
}
```

For example the script is attached to a GameObject : So when the player is getting close to distance 1.7 from the security keypad it will trigger something:

[image: Script is attached to the security keypad]

In this script I'm using the InteractableItem enum :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableItem[] lookObj = null;
    public GameObject objToThrow;
    public Text text;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = true;
    public float throwSpeed;
    public bool handFinishedMove = false;

    private List<InteractableItem> allDetectedItems;
    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        allDetectedItems = new List<InteractableItem>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            allDetectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                    allDetectedItems.Add(target);
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                if(primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow)
                {
                    RightHandToTarget = true;
                }

                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget && primaryTarget.IsAnyAction())
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);

                    // -> new code block
                    if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                    {
                        

                        if(primaryTarget.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
                        // call your funtion to shoot something here
                        StartCoroutine(ThrowObject(objToThrow.transform, primaryTarget.transform.position, 30f));
                    }

                    if(finalLookWeight > 0.9f)
                    {
                        handFinishedMove = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show primary object found by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                text.text = primaryTarget.description;
            }
            else
            {
                text.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ThrowObject(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition, time);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the last script is attached to a Carte and do some actions in two conditions:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class UnlockCrate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animation anim;
    public IKControl ikControl;
    public GameObject securityKeyPad;
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCam;
    public CinemachineFreeLook freeLookCam;
    public CamerasControl camerasContorl;

    private bool playAnimOnce = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!playAnimOnce)
        {
            if (ikControl.handFinishedMove == true)
            {
                securityKeyPad.SetActive(true);
                virtualCam.enabled = true;
                freeLookCam.enabled = false;
                Cursor.visible = true;
                camerasContorl.enabled = false; 
            }

            playAnimOnce = true;
        }
        else if (playAnimOnce)
        {
            securityKeyPad.SetActive(false);
            virtualCam.enabled = false;
            freeLookCam.enabled = true;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            camerasContorl.enabled = true;
            playAnimOnce = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the last script UnlockCrate the problem is that the flag playAnimOnce is all the time change between false and true. I need somehow to use the flag but also to check the distance from the security keypad. I could add a local distance check in the UnlockCrate and check the distance from the player or to check between the player and the security keypad.

But the idea is to use the InteractableItem script on many objects to make actions or to get description. But I want to do it with the distance in the InteractableItem. If the player distance is 1.7 from the security keypad then do something in the UnlockCrate script.

If the player distance from other object for example a tree the distance is 55 then do something with the tree.

The question is a bit long but all the scripts are connected. I'm not sure what to reduce from the scripts.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you want this code to do instead. Try walking us through a scenario, "On frame 1, playAnimOnce is false. I want X Y and Z to happen. On frame 2, I want A, B, C to happen. ... on frame 10, playAnimOnce changes to true, and P, Q, R should happen..."

Comment: @DMGregory For some reason I forgot to add the other scripts and explain.

Comment: Can't you use OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit to accomplish exactly what you are trying to do? Just add a trigger collider to your object, and when the player collides with the trigger then play the animation. when they exit then play the other one. Sorry if I am oversimplifying the problem.